# Matlab MEX error: undefined symbol: mexGetVariableWithObject

Tags: matlab, mex

For some strange reason, without changing anything I now get in my Matlab code the following error:

```
??? Invalid MEX-file
'/code/Matlab/MEX/build/FXP/func_fr1x32.mexa64':
/code/Matlab/MEX/build/FXP/func_fr1x32.mexa64:
undefined symbol: mexGetVariableWithObject.
```

The function "mexGetVariableWithObject" is however never called from any function. I could not find any references to this function and I have no idea what it is doing. Has anyone ever seen this error? What could be the cause of it?

I compile the MEX files with gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

For the "future generations" which may observe similar error, the problem was that the MEX file was compiled on a different version of Matlab (2017a) than on which it was later used (2008b). Recompiling the MEX files on the same Matlab version solved the issue.